# Laravel not loading React component

Tags: reactjs, laravel

My exact message, using
Laravel 5.6, "react": "^16.8.0", "react-dom": "^16.8.0",

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Pricing`.
    in Pricing
```

resources/assets/js/

```
require('./components/Reactapp');
```

Reactapp.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Pricing from './Pricing';

ReactDOM.render(<Pricing />, document.getElementById('reactApp'));
```

Pricing.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CarouselPhotos from './CarouselPhotos';
import { Col, Container, Dropdown, DropdownButton, Form, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Pricing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
// render stuff here
        );
    }
}
```

Can't figure out why I get this error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this error more and checking other answers related to this.  It has nothing to do with this error:

```
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

In my component there was some error with this:

```
import { Col, Container, Dropdown, DropdownButton, Form, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
    <Form>
    <Form.Group controlId="formGroupJobName">
      <Form.Label>Job Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter your job name" />
    </Form.Group>
    </Form>
```

I honesty don't know or see the problem with this component but it was initiating the error.  My recommendation for this type of error is to strip down the component and try to pin point what inner component is causing it.